# Finding nil in optional when I know there is data

Tags: swift, null, option-type

I am getting the error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

but I am pretty sure there is data since when I use NSLog I see the data stored in the variables.

**Action** has three fields - **name**(String), **data**(NSDate), and **count**(Int).
I create a checkbox Action, set values to each of its fields, then try to print it in a text field using **addTextToBottomField**

```
var checkBox = Action(name: sender.currentTitle!) // sender is a UIButton
checkBox.actionStarted = NSDate()
checkBox.count++
main_vc.addTextToBottomField(checkBox)

func addTextToBottomField(a: Action) {
    bottomReportTextView.insertText("\(a.name) (\(a.count)) - \(a.actionStarted)\n")
}
```

I get the error on the line inside of addTextToBottomField

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT:

When I print those fields using

```
NSLog(checkbox.name)
NSLog("\(checkbox.actionStarted)")
NSLog("\(checkbox.count)")
```

In the console I see the following, so I know they have values

```
2015-05-01 15:21:29.797 App[2411:116502] Button Label 1
2015-05-01 15:21:29.799 App[2411:116502] 2015-05-01 19:21:29 +0000
2015-05-01 15:21:29.799 App[2411:116502] 1
```

Comment: From your description those three fields are not optionals, so are not being unwrapped so are not causing the error. Is bottomReportTextView nil?

Comment: @AliBeadle Thanks for the response. bottomReportTextView is a UITextView that I havent done anything to except try to insert text to. Am I missing something?

Comment: You could try putting a breakpoint on the line that is causing the error and checking if bottomReportTextView is really nil. If so then that is the problem. How have you created bottomReportTextView? If it is on a storyboard is it properly linked to your code? If you created it programatically can you post that code?

Comment: @AliBeadle I created it on the storyboard and linked it to my code which is why I didn't expect any errors with it, hmm

Comment: Links to storyboard can become broken (e.g. renaming things or accidentally editing the outlet) so it is worth a check.